# PAT for School - Bank App (Methods and Reading Text Files with Delimitation)

Tags: java, netbeans

Here are my program's methods:

```
package ItPatPackage;

//Defines a banking Client

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Client
{

//attributes
private String clientName;
    private String clientPass;
private int accountNum;
private double currentBal;
private double savingsBal;
    private boolean verify;

//default constructor

public Client()
{
    clientName = "";
            clientPass = "";
    accountNum = 0;
    currentBal = 0.0;
    savingsBal = 0.0;
            verify = false;

}
//parameterised constructor
private Client(String username,String password,int accNum, double
curBal,double savBal, boolean ver)
{
    clientName = username;
            clientPass = password;
    accountNum = accNum;
    currentBal = curBal;
    savingsBal = savBal;
            verify = ver;
}

//get methods
public String getClientName()
{
    return clientName;
}
    public String getClientPass()
    {
            return clientPass;
    }
public int getAccNum()
{
    return accountNum;
}   
 public double getCurrentBal()
{
    return currentBal;
}
public double getSavingsBal()
{
    return savingsBal;
}   
    public boolean getClientVerify()
{
    return verify;
}

//mutator methods
public void setClientName(String username)
{
    clientName= username;
}
public void setClientPass(String password)
{
    clientPass = password;
}   

//deposit
public void depositSavings(double ds)
{
    savingsBal = savingsBal + ds;
}
public void depositCurrent(double dc)
{
    currentBal = currentBal + dc;
}
//withdraw
public void withdrawSavings(double ws)
    {
            if (ws<savingsBal){
            savingsBal = savingsBal - ws;
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient Funds. 
\nYour Savings Balance is: R" + savingsBal);
            }
    }
    public void withdrawCurrent(double wc)
    {
            if (wc<currentBal){
            currentBal = currentBal - wc;
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient Funds.
\nYour Current Balance is: R" + currentBal);
            }
    }
//transfer  
    public void transferStoC(double sc)
    {
            if (sc<savingsBal){
            savingsBal = savingsBal - sc;
            currentBal = savingsBal + sc;
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient Funds.
 \nYour Savings Balance is: R" + savingsBal);
            }
    }
    public void transferCtoS(double cs)
    {
            if (cs<savingsBal){
            savingsBal = savingsBal + cs;
            currentBal = savingsBal - cs;
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient Funds. 
\nYour Current Balance is: R" + currentBal);
            }
    }
    //: Creates New Client
    public void newClient(String username,String password) throws 
IOException
    {
        clientName = username;
        clientPass = password;
        accountNum = (int)(Math.random()*100000);
        savingsBal = (int)((Math.random()*100000000)) / 100.0;
        currentBal = (int)((Math.random()*100000000)) / 100.0;
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (new     
FileWriter("ClientDatabase.txt",true));

 bw.write(clientName+"_"+clientPass+"_"+accountNum+"_"+currentBal+"_"+savingsBal+"_");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
                }
    //: Verifies new Client (THIS IS WHAT DOESN'T WORK, ALONG WITH THE CODE I WILL POST AFTER THIS
    public boolean clientVerify(String checkUsername, String checkPassword)
    {
        try 
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ClientDatabase.txt"));
            String s;
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null){
                String line = br.readLine();
                String part[] = line.split("_");
                if ((part[0].equals(checkUsername))|(part[1].equals(checkPassword))){
                    accountNum = Integer.parseInt(part[3]);
                    currentBal = Double.parseDouble(part[4]);
                    savingsBal = Double.parseDouble(part[5]);
                    verify = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException | NumberFormatException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
        }
        return verify;
    }
}
```

My Log In Button's code is as follows:

```
private void btnLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String checkUsername = txfUsername.getText();
String checkPassword = txfPassword.getText();
Client cl1 = new Client();
boolean verify = cl1.clientVerify(checkUsername, checkPassword);
if (verify==true){
    OptionsPage options = new OptionsPage();
    options.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}
else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username/Password do not match or     do not exist.");
}    
}
```

I have been having trouble with my "clientVerify" method, which works for my "Log In Button", as seen above, and I'm not sure which part is wrong.. It doesn't seem to work, and I don't think that my BufferedReader is reading from the text file properly. (That's the only thing I could think of that may be wrong, correct me if it's something else.)
All that comes up no matter the user input is a JOptionPane Message Dialog saying "Error", and then "Username/Password do not match or do not exist". I have checked the text file and the information is all there perfectly seperated by "_".
Another possibility is that my methods aren't changing from what I have entered them as in the default constructor. I'll admit I'm new to methods so that could be a possibility.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
String line;
    Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\nik\\Documents\\Programming\\TextFiles\\Events.txt");
    try {
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(Files.newInputStream(file));
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
```

try using this code to try to get to the path of the Text File. Because your methods seems in order, but maybe your program is having trouble finding your text file. Hope this works.

Comment: Nah, the exact same thing keeps happening. I genuinely have no idea what I'm doing wrong as everything seems to look fine and there are no errors at all.